# return value in nodejs function

Tags: node.js, nodes, node-modules, async.js

I am new in nodejs, while I write a function, it's not working for return a value in function. I fetch result from mysql then return to function. I know the reason because nodejs default is async. How can I fix my problem? this my source code:

```
function getSlaveURL() {
var sqlQuery = "SELECT url FROM `slave` WHERE `id`='2' LIMIT 1";
var returnValue = "";
db.query(sqlQuery, function (error, rows) {
    if (error) {
        returnValue = "";
    } else {
        returnValue = rows[0]['url'];
        console.log("in function result: " + returnValue);
    }
});
return returnValue;
}
console.log("out function result: " + getSlaveURL());
```

=> result:

out function result:

in function result: http://localhost/mynodejs_slave/

Please help me to fix this problem.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Pass callback function or using `Promise` to do it.
Or you can also use `generator` or `async/await` if your node.js version support.
    Promise:

```
var getSlaveURL = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var sqlQuery = "SELECT url FROM `slave` WHERE `id`='2' LIMIT 1";
    var returnValue = "";
    db.query(sqlQuery, function(error, rows) {
        if (error) {
            returnValue = "";
        } else {
            returnValue = rows[0]['url'];
            console.log("in function result: " + returnValue);
        }
        resolve(returnValue)
    });
});

getSlaveURL.then(function(returnValue) {
    console.log("out function result: " + returnValue);
});
```

async/await:

```
var query = function(sql) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var returnValue = "";
        db.query(sql, function(error, rows) {
            if (error) {
                returnValue = "";
            } else {
                returnValue = rows[0]['url'];
                console.log("in function result: " + returnValue);
            }
            resolve(returnValue)
        });
    });
};

var getSlaveURL = async function() {
    var sqlQuery = "SELECT url FROM `slave` WHERE `id`='2' LIMIT 1";
    let result = await query(sqlQuery)
    console.log("out function result: " + result);
};

getSlaveURL();
```

Comment: Thank you for replied me,
May you help to update this function using async/await ?

Comment: It the same, change `db.query` to `promise`, and then `await` it.@munyso

Comment: Please help to write full function for me, because I don't know how to write it by using async/await. Thank you!

Comment: I updated the function using `async/await`

Comment: Dear @Cr your solution is worked. perfect thank!